# Keep track of time against fixed time accurately in python

Tags: python-2.7, time

My problem is that I have fixed predefined time specified in a file the following way

> start time1:10:00:00
>
> end time1: 11:40:42
>
> start time2: 16:00:00
>
> end time2: 19:52:50
>
> start time3: 20:01:01
>
> end time3 : 23:59:59

and I have a simple counter which starts from 0 at exactly 10:00:00 and then again starts from 0 at 16:00:00 and so on. The counter doesn't increments on the basis of time increment but some other process increments it independent of time. Thus counter should go back to 0 exactly at start time and rest of counter values will be independent of time. Any suggestion how can I achieve this? Thus my main problem is how can I be accurate? The counter should turn to 0 at exactly start time neither 1 second behind nor 1 second earlier.
My code is something like this

```
while True:
    if process:
        count += 1
    else: pass
```

Thus my code at all times will remain in this while loop.

Comment: Create a function that is called to update the counter. In this function, if the current hour is > 10 and less than 16, send back the value of the counter incremented by one, otherwise send 1. Since you are only updating the counter once your "work" is done, you don't need to be accurate on when the counter resets, just that between your intervals of 10 and 16 hours, it should not reset but increment. Even if you were to reset the counter at exactly 10, you don't need the value of the counter unless your work process is completed (that's when you need to increment it).  I hope that made sense.

Comment: I can not increment the counter it will updated by some other on which I have no control. I need to be accurate since suppose I reset counter at 10:00:02 and other process is incrementing counter at rate of 1 sec then I will miss out a event.

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather inexact but seems the main pecularity is how an "other process" does increment of the counter. If all time is synchronized, and there is a shared file access, you can use a shared file to keep counter value (increment and/or clear). If it's unable, start a server in the main process which will get notifications to increment the counter; in that case, the main details is required wall time accuracy. Who will detect when an event happened - server or a remote process?

UPDATE: it's also unclear what is "process" in your code example(). Is at an external flag with auto resetting on reading? Shall you reset it manually? There could be races between modifying and resetting, if not properly cared.

Comment: The other process is basically no. of items coming out of production line. Thus I don't care about end time since production line will automatically stop at end time so counter will stop at end time but at start the counter should turn to 0 and after that it will be incremented by the no. of items coming out of production line.

Comment: If so, you can reset the counter in the middle of off-time (e.g. at 14:00 and 19:55).

Comment: Yes that is possible but in the example their is large gap between end time and start time. What if end time is 16:00:00 and start time is 16:00:01?  How can I be more accurate so as not to miss out 1 sec interval.

Comment: If intervals are too close, you either detect timestamps in the server - if so, it's event engine task to generate notify as close as possible to the change moment, or in a remote process - if so, response could be late so you should keep the previous period counter until a collecting timeout is expired, and compare remote timestamps with the range margin.